# SQL: Group by on value1 and "not" value1?

Tags: sql, db2, database-agnostic

I have a table with something like the following:

```
OrderNo, OrderType
1, Type1
2, Type1
3, Type2
4, Type3
5, Type4
```

Doing a "group by" on OrderType is easy but is there a way to do a "group by" to get something like:

```
OrderCount, OrderType
2, Type1
3, Not Type1
```

This is DB2 but ideally I am looking for a solution that will work regardless of DB vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Select Case OrderType When 'Type1' Then 'Type1'
            Else 'NotType1' End OrderType, 
       Count(*) OrderCount
From Table
Group By Case OrderType When 'Type1' Then 'Type1'
              Else 'NotType1' End
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a clear, simple example that works nicely.

Answer (score 7):

`group by case when OrderType = 'type1' then 'type1' else 'not type 1' end`